# Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: Issue(Blocking) while automating hybrid app using appium

Tags: appium

Am in the process of automating hybrid mobile app using Appium. There is a part in the app which loads frevo form, For which UI Automator viewer returns below error:

Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!.

For all the other part of the app, UI Automator viewer returns as expected.

Can someone help in overcoming the above blocker?

Android Version 5.0.1(api 21)
Appium Version 1.4.0.0

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to stop your appium server, disconnect and connect your device again. This should work